# How to format multiple JSON objects in an Array

Tags: javascript, json

I want to have a JSON object which contains multiple person objects. Is there a better way to format this? What I did below is have a `result` key which would be an array consisting of arrays (which have the JSON person object inside of the inner array).

```
{
result: [
            [
              {
                "name": "Josh",
                "age": 15
              }
            ],

            [
              {
                "name": "Joe",
                "age": 16
              }
            ]
       ]
}
```

Then in the for loop I do something like this:

```
var nameArray = result[0];
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsInJSONObject; i++) {
    newNameArray.push(nameArray[i].firstPerson);        
}
```

Comment: not sure why you have an array of arrays that have a single item. `result` could be a simple array of objects (p.s. these are objects, not JSON. JSON may be how you retrieve the data, but this isn't JSON you are working with)

Comment: It's to separate out the different person objects. Like I want to loop through all of them using a for loop. Like each array inside of the result array is one person object.

Comment: you're wrapping each object in an array containing only that object, that seems useless

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but having the "inner" array with a single item every time is pointless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No point in having each person object wrapped inside it's own array. Unless there is some other grouping that needs done all you should need is one array that contains all the person objects

```
result: [

          {
            "name": "Josh",
            "age": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "Joe",
            "age": 16
          }

   ]
```

This array can be sorted by ages or names, filtered etc

Comment: How would I loop through the result array then to access each person object individually?

Comment: Loop is much simpler now `result.forEach(function(person){ console.log(person.name) })`

Comment: Oh haha I'm stupid. Each position in the array is an object. I was overthinking this too much. Thank you!

Comment: Yup I think the light bulb just went off.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep object like that, something like this work. pleases try this one

```js
var pList = {
  people: [{
    'name': 'Josh',
    'age': 15
  }, {
    'name': 'Joe',
    'age': 16
  }],
  animal: [{
    'type': 'Dog',
    'legs': 4
  }, {
    'type': 'Bird',
    'legs': 2
  }]
};

[].forEach.call(pList.people, function(p) {
    // can push its value into new array or else
    console.log(`${p.name} -- ${p.age}`);
  })
  //or
pList.animal.forEach(function(a) {
  console.log(`${a.type} -- ${a.legs}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your list of objects:

```
var a = [];
a.push({ "name" : "Joe", "age" : 16 });
a.push({ "name" : "John", "age" : 17 });
```

Here is how you can create JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(a);
```

Here is the result:

```
[{"name":"John","age":17},{"name":"Joe","age":16}]
```

Here is how you can iterate through your array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { console.log(a[i]) }
```